# NSMutableDictionary with non-copyable UIView keys (using CFDictionary) crashes on iOS SDK 6, yet OK on 5.1

Tags: objective-c, nsmutabledictionary, ios6

So I was using TLMutableDictionaryNoncopiedKeys Category for NSMutableDictionary found [here](http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/214295-storing-values-in-dictionary-with-their-address-as-the-key.html) that allows using non-copyable objects as keys for dictionary (I need object-to-object mapping). All was good till I was told app crashes in iOS 6. So I downloaded XCode 4.5 with iOS 6 to test and it appears that there's some problem with CFDictionary functions. If I pass UIView as a key (in my category method) it crashes with:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIView copyWithZone:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x719ff70'
```

More details from AppCode debugger:

```
objc_exception_throw
-[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:]
__forwarding__
_CF_forwarding_prep_0
-[__NSDictionaryM setObject:forKey:]
-[NSMutableDictionary __addObject:forKey:]
CFDictionaryAddValue
-[NSMutableDictionary(TLMutableDictionaryNoncopiedKeys) setObject:forUncopiedKey:]
```

I made a test project. It works well with iOS 5.1 Simulator, but crashes with 6.

Could anyone shed some light on this?

Full project is [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/djqgh7h79v3zsew/DictionaryTest.zip). And here are some listings:

Category:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>


@interface NSMutableDictionary (TLMutableDictionaryNoncopiedKeys)

- (void)setObject:(id)anObject forUncopiedKey:(id)aKey;

@end

----------------------------------------------------------------------

#import "NSMutableDictionary+TLMutableDictionaryNoncopiedKeys.h"

@implementation NSMutableDictionary (TLMutableDictionaryNoncopiedKeys)

- (void)setObject:(id)anObject forUncopiedKey:(id)aKey
{
    CFMutableDictionaryRef selfCF = (CFMutableDictionaryRef)self;
    Boolean keyAlreadySet = CFDictionaryContainsKey(selfCF, aKey);
    if (keyAlreadySet) {
        CFDictionaryReplaceValue(selfCF, aKey, anObject);
    }
    else {
        CFDictionaryAddValue(selfCF, aKey, anObject);
    }
}

@end
```

Usage:

```
#import "NSMutableDictionary+TLMutableDictionaryNoncopiedKeys.h"
...
NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
UIView *key = [[UIView alloc] init];
[dict setObject:key forUncopiedKey:key];
```

Comment: I think you'll find it is hard to comment when iOS 6 is under NDA!

Comment: But there's nothing iOS 6 - specific... Should I ask this somewhere else?

Comment: Note that there should be a stack dump that will point you directly at the particular `copyWithZone` call that is erroneously being fed a UIView.

Comment: @HotLicks it's that setObject:forUncopiedKey: call, but to be more precise I updated question.

Comment: Why not just subclass that poor dictionary? This **is** a valid reason for subclassing...

Comment: @H2CO3 and how the object-to-object mapping implementation would look like?

Comment: @Pavelfljōt I can imagine two C arrays for the keys and values, linked by their indices.